# Change appearance of highlighted references (C++, C#, Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional. Reference highlighting for C++ and C# code is enabled in `Options > Text Editor` as follows:

- `C/C++ > Advanced > References > Disable Reference Highlighting` (set to False)
- `C# > Advanced > Highlighting > Highlight references to symbol under cursor` (tick)

This works fine, but the references are too bright, making it difficult to see the cursor. In dense code (with many references) you get a confusing clutter.

[image: Example reference highlighting]

Ideally highlighted references would be more subtle, but I was not able to find an appropriate option under `Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors`. Can the appearance of highlighted references be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Toos > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > **Highlighted References**.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.7